# Why did Cersei say yes to the Mountain to kill Jaime?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf", why did Cersei say yes to the Mountain to kill Jaime?

Comment: Because she wanted him dead I guess. The more interesting question would be, why did she want him dead?

Comment: @JAD To be honest I don't think she ever wanted him dead, it appears to have been a bluff to try and get Jaime to stay.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, i agree it was a bluff .. i was shocked when she  nodded, and above all she didnt even nod to kill Tyrion,who she hates but for Jaime she did !!!!

Comment: @Aryana Aye, the way the scene played out was a bit awkward when you see what their intentions were though if you look in the linked thread she likely let Tyrion go to make him look foolish later on.

Comment: I think Cersei made a pact with Tyrion, and he will be spying on Daenerys for her. or maybe he already was spying on her for all this long so it was easy for Tyrion to accept Cersei's condition that she might have told him.

Comment: I think you have enough rep, if so do you want to join us in [The Quill and Tankard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/the-quill-and-tankard)? It is the chatroom for GoT/ASOIAF where these sorts of discussions are better placed.

Comment: Count me in ! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### She didn't

Whilst it does look that way in the scene because Cersei nods at the Mountain the [official script](http://m.emmys.com/sites/default/files/collateral/118%20Game%20Of%20Thrones%20-%20The%20Dragon%20and%20the%20Wolf.pdf) gives us some more information on what actually happens. To cut it down into chunks.

Jaime and Cersei have a brief argument where Jaime wants to ride north but Cersei feels betrayed by this. To her it feels like Jaime is abandoning her and because it is against hr orders she calls this treason which is punishable by death.

> JAIME: I pledged to ride north. I intend to honor that pledge.
>
> CERSEI: And that would be treason.
>
> JAIME: Treason?!
>
> CERSEI: Disobeying your Queen’s command. Fighting with her enemies. What would you call it?
>
> *Jaime considers his response for a long beat, staring at his sister, his lover, his queen.*
>
> JAIME: It doesn’t matter what I’d call it.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>

They then have a brief argument over what Cersei's plans actually are when the Mountain blocks him from leaving. Jaime doesn't believe Cersei will kill him because all they have is each other now. However, Cersei implies that's not actually true by implying she is pregnant.

> *He turns to go but finds that the Mountain stands directly in his way.*
>
> CERSEI: I told you no one walks away from me.
>
> *Jaime turns and looks at her again.*
>
> JAIME: Are you going to order him to kill me?
>
> *Cersei stares at him.*
>
> JAIME: I’m the only one you have left. Our children are gone. Our father is gone. It’s just me and you now.
>
> CERSEI: There’s one more yet to come.
>
> *Jaime nods.*
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>

Then Jaime calls her bluff, and Cersei orders the Mountain to draw his sword, this is the order we see on screen. She doesn't, at this point, order him to kill Jaime.

> JAIME: Give the order, then.
>
> *He watches her and waits.*
>
> *The Mountain waits for a command from his queen.*
>
> *She nods. The smallest possible nod.*
>
> *The Mountain draws his sword.*
>
> *Jaime knows there’s no point fighting. He knows he will be cut in half.*
>
> *He stares at his sister for a long beat.*
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>

Then Jaime makes up his mind that Cersei won't actually kill him and walks off. It turns out he was right as she never does give the final kill command.

> JAIME: (quiet) I don’t believe you.
>
> *After a long beat, Jaime turns and walks away, right past the Mountain and his drawn sword.*
>
> *Cersei watches. She does not give the command.*
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>